# Xorg/Gnome-shell CPU spikes - any action

Tags: gnome

I'm experiencing CPU spikes with Xorg + gnome-shell (on Ubuntu 20.04 - fresh install). Disabling all extensions does not help. The attached screenshot is with no applications/windows open and only continuously moving my mouse around - yet it's using 60.7% of 1 core. This seems excessive. Does anybody have any suggestions on what I can do to help this? I do experience a visual lag at times with Gnome, which I never did on 19.10. Overtime, the GUI tends to slow down the more Ubuntu is logged in. Disabling animations etc. does not help.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**:

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 9 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 17 20:15 .
drwx------ 3 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 17 20:14 ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 12 15:12 cpupower@mko-sl.de
drwxrwxr-x 5 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 12 10:44 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 6 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 12 14:50 gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de
drwxrwxr-x 2 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 12 14:50 Move_Clock@rmy.pobox.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 12 23:22 remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 17 19:21 transparent-panel@fthx
drwxrwxr-x 6 tjcooper tjcooper 4096 Jun 12 14:51 Vitals@CoreCoding.com

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 13 16:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 12 10:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 10:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 12 10:48 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
ps auxc | grep gnome-shell
tjcooper    7447  5.4  0.9 4759872 324144 ?      Ssl  14:53   5:26 gnome-shell
tjcooper    7842  0.0  0.0 513008 26776 ?        Sl   14:53   0:00 gnome-shell-cal
```

Comment: You have two copies of gnome-shell running on your user account. Why/how? Did you disable GNOME Shell extensions? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Moving the mouse while viewing `top` or `htop` will give you inaccurate results. With no mouse movement, gnome-shell should be less than 3% of CPU.

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the question. Note: i've re-enabled my extensions since it made no difference to remove/disable them.

Comment: I see gnome-shell running twice in htop. `ps auxc | grep gnome-shell`. Reboot and watch for which app or gnome-shell extension is starting the second copy.

Comment: @heynnema Added another edit with the output. I'm not sure how to watch for which app/extension initiates the second copy. Isn't htop showing multiple gnome-shell instances because they're split across different threads?

Comment: Check `top` against `htop` and see if `htop` incorrectly shows two gnome-shell processes under your login name. Use the `ps` command after a fresh reboot to check for two processes, and again after starting various apps/extensions. When disabling extensions, restart gnome-shell each time.

Comment: @heynnema Top lists only a single gnome-shell instance - htop (incorrectly) lists two.

Comment: Then my answer is, with no mouse movement, or no bad gnome-shell extensions, gnome-shell should be less than 3% of CPU. After a while, gnome-shell starts taking a lot of memory, restart gnome-shell with alt+f2 then r then enter.