# Gnome shell with RDP signifigant lag and CPU spikes on any action

Tags: gnome, 22.04, xorg, gnome-shell

I have a ubuntu remote server to which I use RDP to connect from my local windows machine. I have installed Xrdp and Xorg and the connection seems to work, when performing any action the UI is very slow to respond, lags, and gnome seems to spike CPU usage (see attached screenshot). It stays around 1% on idle. The magnitude of the CPU spikes do seem to be somehow related to the action performed, with faster, more intensive actions (opening and moving multiple windows, opening app menu, etc) causing larger spikes, while simple navigation inside a folder does not cause significant spikes or lag.

Note: there seems to be no lag or spikes while on the login screen. All transitions on this screen work smoothly.

I have tried the options described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251248/xorg-gnome-shell-cpu-spikes-any-action), without much success. I have also removed the seconds counter from the display calendar, and it did seem to improve the performance a bit. I have also tried to reinstall gnome, without any effect.

[image: CPU spike while attempting to move a window across the screen]

Physical setup: Dell R740, S/N 3LQVGY2 CPU: Xeon Silver 4110 2 szt. RAM: 16GB 2666MHz RDIMM 2 szt. RAID H730P

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Video:

```shell
> lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller [102b:0536] (rev 04)
        DeviceName: Embedded Video
```

Gnome version:

```shell
> gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.9
```

Xrdp verion:

```shell
> stdbuf  -o0  xrdp -v

xrdp 0.9.17
```

Xorg version:

```shell
> sudo X -version

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux hwpmt 5.15.0-79-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 10 16:07:21 UTC 2023 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-79-generic root=UUID=bd3dc8a2-f8ef-45f1-afba-597ef0e657af ro
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Direct rendering:

```shell
> glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
```